# How to manage python dependecies from vim plugins using a virtualenv?

Tags: python, vim

I have vim with python2 support, but normally I work with python3.

I have some vim plugins which require to install some python packages to do their job, so I created a python virtualenv to install them.

One of the plugins is [vim-flake8](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8). The required python package, [flake8](https://flake8.readthedocs.org), returns different values based on the python version, so I installed [flake8](https://flake8.readthedocs.org) in a python3 virtualenv. The vim plugin only uses [flake8](https://flake8.readthedocs.org) from the command line, thus I just update the vim $PATH variable on my `.vimrc` file to include the bin folder of this virtualenv.

Other of the plugins is [vim-rst-tables](https://github.com/nvie/vim-rst-tables). This plugin uses the vim python interface, and has a python package dependency, [vim_bridge](https://github.com/nvie/vim_bridge). Since vim is compiled with python2 support, I created a new python2 virtualenv to install here the dependencies, and in my `.vimrc` I update the vim's python `sys.path` with this call: `site.addsitedir('/path/to/site_packages')`

I find all the process a little complicated, is there a better/easier way to manage the python dependencies? And also how to handle the case where a python dependency is required from the command line and from vim's python interface?

Comment: I've been trying to come up with a good solution to this myself, but no luck so far. I don't think virtualenv has the notion of a global environment. RVM has such a notion, and I'd normally put dependencies that I want available to all RVM environments in the global environment. At the moment I'm just using the system Python and its environment. You could install vim_bridge system wide, of course, but a virtualized solution would be nice.

Comment: A link to my vimrc configuration, not best solution, but uses virtualenvs.

[Link to github](https://github.com/jlesquembre/vim/blob/796f3a1b0a10a8286398fc7c50408739150136d5/vimrc#L125-L140)

Answer (score 0):

I find that a tool like:

pythonbrew (although it's deprecated) : https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew

and

pyenv : https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

are tools that make easier to manage and install dependencies. I particularly find pythonbrew quite useful and I am currently using it.

The reason why they're so useful is because they allow you to use a completely separate python from your system one and the installation process of the actual tool is relatively easy (you may get a couple of hiccups with some packages, but it can be resolved somewhat easily with communities like SO).

Normally with a tool like pythonbrew you can install any dependency and it will place it into the version of python you are currently using without affecting your system-version.

I recommend you try it out and see for yourself.

I hope this answers your questions.